# NSSM daily rotation

Tags: logrotate, nssm

How to enable on the "daily" rotation. I need to rotate the logs strictly at 00:00 every day.
There is no word about it in the documentation, or i dont understand something.

I have service installation script "install.bat" in which all the parameters related to log rotation:

```
...
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppStdout C:\Server%SNAME%\Logs\server.log
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppStderr C:\Server%SNAME%\Logs\server.log
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppStdoutCreationDisposition 4
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppStderrCreationDisposition 4
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppRotateFiles 1
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppRotateOnline 1
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppRotateSeconds 86400
nssm set Server%SNAME% AppRotateBytes 52428800
...
```

the only thing I came up with is calling, from another service, the rotation command:

```
nssm rotate %Server%SNAME%
```

and it works, but I think there are better options.

How else to rotate nssm logs every day at a strict time?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same situation, not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, I don't think it's in capabilities of NSSM. You can specify time between rotations, but it's related to time, since the service is running. It's not *cron-like* record.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack, but... You can use Windows Task Scheduler and create there new "Basic Task" that triggers daily at specified time and set Action for it to "nssm rotate <service_name>".
Check "Task" there. It has more sophisticated control of conditions and settings.